# What is the difference between SchemaLink and HttpLink for ApolloClient?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

For `ApolloClient` we can use either `SchemaLink` or `HttpLink`.

Is there any advantage for using one or other?

```
// SchemaLink
function createLink() {
  const { SchemaLink } = require('@apollo/client/link/schema')
  const { schema } = require('../server/schema')
  return new SchemaLink({ schema })
}
```

---

```
// HttpLink
function createLink() {
  const { HttpLink } = require('@apollo/client/link/http')
  return new HttpLink({
    uri: '/api/graphql',
    credentials: 'same-origin'
}
```

---

```
// ApolloClient
function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: createLink(),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpLink` is forwarding GraphQL queries through a HTTP POST request to the provided endpoint `uri`.

The `SchemaLink`, well, [the documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/schema/) explains what it does:

> The schema link provides a graphql execution environment, which allows you to perform GraphQL operations on a provided schema. This type of behavior is commonly used for server-side rendering (SSR) to avoid network calls and mocking data.

So while the `HttpLink` is used to hit a distant GraphQL server through the network (usually, in a client application context), the `SchemaLink` is used when the server is available locally, where we can import the schema in the same source as a server-side project, like in your example snippet.

> Is there any advantage for using one or other?

They're meant for different use-cases, while nothing stops you from doing HTTP calls on the server to an endpoint on the same server (e.g. localhost), using the schema link to query a local schema might be better depending on the project's architecture (Is the GraphQL server deployed to an external host where the schema wouldn't be available locally? etc.)

They could also both be used, e.g. `HttpLink` on the browser side and `SchemaLink` for server-side rendering of the same React application.